# Getting error Caused by: org.junit.platform.commons.PreconditionViolationException: Unable to parse tag expression

Tags: gradle, junit5

I am trying to migrate my java project from gradle 7.6 version to gradle 8.1 version but while migration I am getting below error.

I am not sure what it is I need to do further. Can someone help me please? Here is the code so far I have got:

```
                if (args[i].split("=")[0].equalsIgnoreCase("SUITE")) {testSuite = args[i].split("=")[1]}
                project.setProperty("country", country)
                System.properties.put("country", country)
                project.setProperty("environment", environment + "." + country)
                System.properties.put("environment", environment + "." + country)
                systemProperties System.properties

                project.logger.lifecycle("Finished extracting params - attempting to kick off tests with JUnit")
                //Find and execute the tests using JUnit by including only the combinations of annotations given in the command line
                useJUnitPlatform {
                    if (project.hasProperty('includeTags')) {includeTags project.getProperty('includeTags')}
                    includeTags "" + country + " & " + testSuite
                    project.logger.lifecycle("Junit Starting - using test suite: " + testSuite + ", country" + country+ " and environment: " + environment)
                }
```

**Error:**

```
org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.TestSuiteExecutionException: Could not complete execution for Gradle Test Executor 6.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.stop(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:64)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:33)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:94)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.stop(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker$3.run(TestWorker.java:193)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.executeAndMaintainThreadName(TestWorker.java:129)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.execute(TestWorker.java:100)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.execute(TestWorker.java:60)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.ActionExecutionWorker.execute(ActionExecutionWorker.java:56)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.call(SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.java:113)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.call(SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.java:65)
    at worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain.run(GradleWorkerMain.java:69)
    at worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain.main(GradleWorkerMain.java:74)
Caused by: org.junit.platform.commons.PreconditionViolationException: Unable to parse tag expression " & SMOKE": missing lhs operand for '&' at index <1>
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.TagFilter.lambda$parse$8(TagFilter.java:181)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.tagexpression.ParseResult.tagExpressionOrThrow(ParseResult.java:42)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.TagFilter.parse(TagFilter.java:180)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
    at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1384)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:482)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:472)
    at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:499)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.TagFilter.parseAll(TagFilter.java:176)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.TagFilter.includeMatching(TagFilter.java:133)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.TagFilter.includeTags(TagFilter.java:89)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.addTagsFilter(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:166)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.createLauncherDiscoveryRequest(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:150)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.access$400(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.processAllTestClasses(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:108)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.access$000(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:90)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.stop(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:85)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.stop(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:62)
    ... 18 more
```

Comment: did you tried anything to resolve error? Also, what is your JUNIT version.